# SSO Implementation Using Windows identity Foundation

Tags: asp.net, .net, single-sign-on, wif, pingfederate

I want to implement SSO in my ASP.Net Web application running on v.4.0 using ping Federate as Identity Provider.I have tried searching through a lot of stuffs on SSO in .net and all but did't got and clarification yet.
Any help to understand the way of doing SSO or and sample application to do is appreciable.

Comment: Take a look at my tutorial here http://www.wiktorzychla.com/2014/11/simplest-saml11-federated-authentication.html and come back with more specific questions.

Comment: @WiktorZychla went through the blog ,thanks many things are clear,will update the question if stuck in implemenatation, thanks